# Resizing font in a relatively-sized element upon mobile zoom

Tags: css, html, mobile, zooming

I have a page with very graphic (not text-based) content. I mention this because it's expected that visitors on mobile devices will pinch to zoom in and out to see either the entire page or focus on a small detail.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=0.3, maximum-scale=1.2">
```

On mobile devices, I have a div at the bottom of the page with

```
.bottom-bar{
    position: absolute; 
    height: 10%;
    bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
}
```

so it will always take up the bottom 10% of the viewport. That's great because that's where I want to place the text that'll always be visible.
The problem is that when a user zooms out the text is tiny. When the user zooms in the text is too large.
So I'm looking for a solution that'll allow me to **resize the text** to always fit the **height** of the container div.

[fitText](http://fittextjs.com/) got me close but sometimes failed - when zooming in, the text often remained to large.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) to fetch the zoom level and then use js to change the font-size property of your text in inverted direction. So if you have a zoom level of 1.2 for example, you devide your default font size by 1.2 and get 13.33px. If you set this, your text will keep the same size but the picture behind it will be zoomed.